# How to use KnockoutJS to observe data on server via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, mvvm, knockout.js

I've played a little with [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/) and have produced the following example, enough to become excited by the idea of building these viewmodels in javascript so that the view can be written in much simpler, declarative manner, i.e. first you define **what you want to observe**, then with the `data-bind` attributes define **what you want to happen** when your viewmodel changes in certain ways.

But all of this is happening only on the client.

**How could I extend this example to use knockoutjs to observe the state of objects on the server e.g. via AJAX calls?**

**index.htm:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <title>Knockout example</title>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/knockout-1.1.1.debug.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- FIRST AREA -->
        <div class="infobox">
            <div data-bind="visible: noNamesFilled">
                <p>This is an example with NO names filled.</p>
            </div>
            <div data-bind="visible: bothNamesFilled">
                <p>This is an example with both names filled.</p>
            </div>
            <div data-bind="visible: firstNameOnlyFilled">
                <p>This is an example with only the first name filled.</p>
            </div>
            <div data-bind="visible: lastNameOnlyFilled">
                <p>This is an example with the last name filled but not the first name</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- SECOND AREA -->
        <p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'" /></p>
        <p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'" /></p>
        <div data-bind="visible: bothNamesFilled">
            <h2 class="normal">Hello, <span data-bind="text: fullName"></span>.</h2>
        </div>
        <div data-bind="visible: firstNameOnlyFilled">
            <h2 class="informal">Hi there <span data-bind="text: fullName"></span>!</h2>
        </div>
        <div data-bind="visible: lastNameOnlyFilled">
            <h2 class="formal">Hello, Mr. <span data-bind="text: fullName"></span>.</h2>
        </div>

        <!-- THIRD AREA -->
        <div data-bind="visible: noNamesFilled">
            <p><span class="bad">:-(</span> Please fill in both names.</p>
        </div>
        <div data-bind="visible: bothNamesFilled">
            <p><span class="good">:-)</span> Good job, both names are filled!</p>
        </div>
        <div data-bind="visible: firstNameOnlyFilled">
            <p><span class="ok">:-(</span> Please fill in the last name, too.</p>
        </div>
        <div data-bind="visible: lastNameOnlyFilled">
            <p><span class="ko">:-(</span> Please fill in the first name as well.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**main.css:**

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0}
body { margin: 10px}
p { margin: 10px}
.infobox {
    background-color: #eee;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.informal {
    color: purple;
    font-family: arial;
}
.normal {
    color: black;
    font-family: new courier;
}
.formal {
    color: black;
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-family: times roman;
    background-color: #eee;
}
.good {
    width: 20px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
.ok {
    width: 20px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.bad {
    width: 20px;
    background-color: tomato;
}
```

**main.js:**

```
window.onload= function() {

    var viewModel = {
        firstName : ko.observable(''),
        lastName : ko.observable('')
    };
    viewModel.fullName = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        return viewModel.firstName() + " " + viewModel.lastName();
    });

    viewModel.bothNamesFilled = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        return viewModel.firstName().length > 0 && viewModel.lastName().length > 0;
    }, this);
    viewModel.firstNameOnlyFilled = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        return viewModel.firstName().length > 0 && viewModel.lastName().length == 0;
    }, this);
    viewModel.lastNameOnlyFilled = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        return viewModel.firstName().length == 0 && viewModel.lastName().length > 0;
    }, this);
    viewModel.noNamesFilled = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        return viewModel.firstName().length == 0 && viewModel.lastName().length == 0;
    }, this);

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use setTimeout to call a function that uses JQuery to make an $.ajax call.  When it returns JSON data, set that data as your view model and finally, setTimeout again to call the function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an updated example that mainly updates main.js to work with JQuery to do the ajax call.

The HTML file includes Knockout 3 instead of 1.  The HTML also includes JQuery latest to make the JQuery functionality work.

The js/server_data.js is there so you have some valid json data to start with.  You can change the url in the $.ajax settings to any serverside script you have but try to set its content type to application/json.  For example, PHP scripts could set the Content-type header like: header('Content-type: application/json'); before printing out the data in JSON format.

new main.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <title>Knockout example</title>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/knockout-3.0.0.debug.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- FIRST AREA -->
        <div class="infobox">
            <div data-bind="visible: noNamesFilled">
                <p>This is an example with NO names filled.</p>
            </div>
            <div data-bind="visible: bothNamesFilled">
                <p>This is an example with both names filled.</p>
            </div>
            <div data-bind="visible: firstNameOnlyFilled">
                <p>This is an example with only the first name filled.</p>
            </div>
            <div data-bind="visible: lastNameOnlyFilled">
                <p>This is an example with the last name filled but not the first name</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- SECOND AREA -->
        <p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'" /></p>
        <p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'" /></p>
        <div data-bind="visible: bothNamesFilled">
            <h2 class="normal">Hello, <span data-bind="text: fullName"></span>.</h2>
        </div>
        <div data-bind="visible: firstNameOnlyFilled">
            <h2 class="informal">Hi there <span data-bind="text: fullName"></span>!</h2>
        </div>
        <div data-bind="visible: lastNameOnlyFilled">
            <h2 class="formal">Hello, Mr. <span data-bind="text: fullName"></span>.</h2>
        </div>

        <!-- THIRD AREA -->
        <div data-bind="visible: noNamesFilled">
            <p><span class="bad">:-(</span> Please fill in both names.</p>
        </div>
        <div data-bind="visible: bothNamesFilled">
            <p><span class="good">:-)</span> Good job, both names are filled!</p>
        </div>
        <div data-bind="visible: firstNameOnlyFilled">
            <p><span class="ok">:-(</span> Please fill in the last name, too.</p>
        </div>
        <div data-bind="visible: lastNameOnlyFilled">
            <p><span class="ko">:-(</span> Please fill in the first name as well.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

js/main.js:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    var viewModel = {
        firstName : ko.observable(''),
        lastName : ko.observable('')
    };
    viewModel.fullName = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        return viewModel.firstName() + " " + viewModel.lastName();
    });

    viewModel.bothNamesFilled = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        return viewModel.firstName().length > 0 && viewModel.lastName().length > 0;
    }, this);
    viewModel.firstNameOnlyFilled = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        return viewModel.firstName().length > 0 && viewModel.lastName().length == 0;
    }, this);
    viewModel.lastNameOnlyFilled = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        return viewModel.firstName().length == 0 && viewModel.lastName().length > 0;
    }, this);
    viewModel.noNamesFilled = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        return viewModel.firstName().length == 0 && viewModel.lastName().length == 0;
    }, this);

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

    // send request to the server to download the server's model information.
    $.ajax(
    {
        'url': 'js/server_data.js',
        'dataType': 'json',
        'method': 'post',
        'error': function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            // error callback in case you play with this code and run into trouble.
            alert('There was a problem handling the ajax request.  The error information is: jqXHR: '
            +jqXHR+", textStatus: "+textStatus+", errorThrown: "+errorThrown);
        },
        'success': function(data)
        {
            // when it is downloaded and parsed to create the "data" parameter, update the viewModel.
            viewModel.firstName(data.firstName);
            viewModel.lastName(data.lastName);
        }
    }
    );
}
);
```

js/server_data.js representing dynamically generated data that might be from a database:

```
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe"
}
```

jsteve has the right general idea but don't use setTimeout if you just want to download the data when the page loads.  Instead, use the JQuery's document ready callback and JQuery's ajax success callback so things run precisely when you want them to.

If you want to continually listen and react to changes to data in the server, look into long poller techniques.  Long poller is more efficient and precisely timed than busy waiting that requires a frequent new request to the server.